# Web API Test using Fiddler return null

Tags: c#, api, fiddler

When i test following API using fiddler always set the parameter myRequest with null value. how i can fix this?

API

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]MyRequest myRequest)
        {

        }
```

Model

```
public class MyRequest
{
    public int[] MyId { get; set; }
}
```

Fiddler Test

```
http://localhost:4037/api/PostTest
```

Request Body

```
{
    "MyRequest": {
        "MyId": [
            1,
            2
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need "MyRequest" in the JSON...

```
{
    "MyId": [
        1,
        2
    ]
}
```

Comment: Also, ensure that the Composer's HTTP Method box shows `POST` and ensure that you have `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` in the Headers box.